# IE Developer Tools - show generated DOM

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

How do I make IE8 Developer Tools to show DOM that was generated after JavaScript was executed? Currently it displays only the static layout. FireBug handles this correctly, but I need to have a look in IE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a refresh button. That should reload the DOM tree.

Comment: IE Developer Tools really should show DOM changes in real-time like Firebug does, but unfortunately this isn't the case...