# <xsl:element> behaving differently in different browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, xslt-2.0

When I use `<xsl:element>` to create dynamic tags, it creates differently in IE and Firefox.

Eg:

Use a browser other than IE.
You can go to URL : "http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp" and select the "[View the Result](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_element.xml)" link below the Example 1.

Now the result is shown in a new window. Now go to Developer tools and select any item.
We can see the "singer" tag is created properly. 
Eg: `<singer>Bob Dylan</singer>`

But when we see the same in IE, the tag is not created properly.

Eg:

```
<singer/>
Text - Bob DyLan
</singer/>
```

Can any one know about this. Is this a bug with IE ? Is there any work around/Solution for this.

Comment: Which version of ie are you talking about? I have never seen any such issue. The link that you have given transforms the xml as expected in IE.

Comment: @KosalaW. Thanks for the update. I have seen this behavior in IE8. It renders properly in UI, but when you see the html code, it looks like what i have mentioned in the Question.

Comment: Tested your sample in ie6 and ie10. Did not see any issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE Developer Tools - show generated DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665147/ie-developer-tools-show-generated-dom)